# How can I prevent users from styling text in a custom Exact Target template?

Tags: marketing-cloud, css

My company has several departments that would like to have their own email newsletters. In order to maintain brand consistency, we would like to hard code certain text styles into custom email templates and prevent users from applying their own styles.

For example, in any given newsletter, all article headers should be Arial, bold, 27px, #346a8a. This is a no-brainer using embedded CSS or inline styles. Most users who will be tasked with publishing the newsletters, however,  will not be familiar with CSS or HTML & inline styles. It will likely be more of a copy & paste scenario.

Is there a method for providing a content type that is pre-styled so that users can simply select the content type, modify the text and save without having to worry about looking at the HTML to make sure it's styled properly?

Answer (score 1):

You could technically create stored content areas that can be pulled into the email, and then edited in the email itself.  This won't edit the original content area, and may not give the exact usage you are looking for, but it would be about as close as you could get.

Comment: Sorry for that - feel free to mark this as answered so everyone knows that it's closed.  If things change, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Kelly's response that if you have an Enterprise account you can make that template shared and configure what sections of it would be editable by various child business units. 
See the following article in documentation: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/shared_items/